# Decrease font size for index in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am writing a presentation with the `beamer`-package, using the `Goettingen`-environment which displays the table of contents in a bar on the right side of the slide. My problem is that the table of contents contains more entries than the side panel supports, creating an overflow. Is there a way to solve that (maybe by decreasing the font size)?

Comment: Is the problem that you have  a table of contents slide that is too long to fit? Or that the navigation bar on the side has too many things in it? A picture of the issue might help.

Comment: Please give us a minimal example in the form of code which illustrates your problem and starts `\documentclass` and ends `\end{document}`.

Comment: Before an MWE is given, I guess there are something like `\setbeamerfont{sidebar right}{\tiny}{}`

Comment: As you might have noticed with the hat-question, a MWE increases the change of an answer.